# Probability that a randomly selected bit string of length 15 is a palindrome

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, palindrome

Question: what is the probability that a randomly selected bit string of length $15$ is a palindrome?

My partial solution is that I know the $15$ length is "$10001010100001$". That's all I know. Can someone help me find and understand the solution?

Comment: If you pick the first bit, how many bits are left free to set to any value?  (It's not 14.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you know that you need the first 7 bits to match the last 7 bits for the string to be a palindrome.

First thing to think about is how many ways can we arrange 7 bits?

Answer: $$2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2=2^7$$

However, don't forget that the $8^{th}$ bit can be either a 1 or a 0. So if the $8^{th}$ bit is a 1 that cuts the number of combinations in half (i.e., $2^7/2$) and similarly if the $8^{th}$ bit is a 0.

Now, we want to know what the probability that a randomly selected bit string of length 15 is a palindrome. For convenience, define the event $E$ as the case that a string of length 15 is a palindrome. Well, we have the following:

\begin{align*}
Pr(E) = Pr(&\text{First 7 bits} = \text{Last 7 bits and the } 8^{th} \text{ bit = 1}\text{ or }\\
&\text{First 7 bits} = \text{Last 7 bits and the } 8^{th} \text{ bit = 0})\\
=Pr(&\text{First 7 bits} = \text{Last 7 bits and the } 8^{th} \text{ bit = 1})+\\
&\text{First 7 bits} = \text{Last 7 bits and the } 8^{th} \text{ bit = 0})\\
=&\frac{1}{2^7/2}+\frac{1}{2^7/2}\\
=&\frac{1}{2^7}
\end{align*}

Comment: @calculus, check out my answer for a different way to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is a string that reads the same backwards as forwards.   Basically, that's symmetry.

So you want the probability that the last $7$ digits are exactly the same as the first $7$ digits, though in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You can calculate all ways of arrangement of $0$ and $1$ for the first $7$ places.  The last $7$ places have to be ordered mirror imaged. Thus they have not be regarded. Then regard that at the 8th place of the string can be a $1$ or a $0$.

Answer (score 0):

For every first 7 bits you need last 7 bits to match in a defined way.

First 7 bits can be arbitrary. So the answer is 1/(2^7)

In general answer is 1/(2^floor(stringlength/2))

Comment: You have forgotten to regard the 8th bit.

Comment: Dude.. It will always match. Might as well it didn't exist.

Comment: Try on a small example and see.

Comment: $01010$ is different from $01110$ and you have to count both.

Comment: You are not getting it. For both string sizes 2 and 3, answer is 1/2.

Comment: You are right I´m not getting it. But your answer is right. Therefore your arguements should be right.

Comment: @calculus, the 8th bit doesn't need to be regarded as the palindrome dual of the 8th bit is the 8th bit. The probability that the 8th bit will be the same as the 8th bit is $1$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp It is another way of thinking than I do, but now I understand it and I do agree. I have counted all possible of arrangements of the first 8 digits and  have divided this number by the number of all possible arrangements of the 15 digit string:$\frac{2^8}{2^{15}}=\frac{1}{2^7}$. Thank you guys for clarifying.

Comment: can I use the above solution @calculus?

Comment: @guest11 Yes you can. Why not ?

Answer (score 0):

For a string of length $n$, the probability of finding a palindromic string should simply be the number of possible palindromic combinations divided by the number of total possible combinations.

For both an even and odd string of length $n$, the total combinations is simply $2^n$. The number of palindrome combinations, however, depends on whether the string is even or odd.

For even, only the first $\frac{n}{2}$ elements of the string are free (the remainder are determined once the first $\frac{n}{2}$ are selected) and so the probability is

EVEN string: $\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}$

For odd, the first $\frac{n+1}{2}$ are free since the middle digit is along the line of symmetry. So, the probability in this case is,

ODD string: $\frac{1}{2^{(n-1)/2}}$

Note that the even case  is equivalent to the odd case + 1.

So, your string of length 15 being a palindrome has the same probability of a string of length 14:

$\frac{1}{2^7}$